# How to Make Form Submit Open Up In A Popup Window

Tags: html, forms, submit

I've seen many website do this, and I think it looks pretty cool. Anyway, I was wondering how you do it.

When a term is searched on the form, I want the results to open in a popup window.

Here is my code for the form submit: http://pastebin.com/NBxz7FQi

Also will this be supported be early versions of internet explorer?

Answer (score 1):

In your form tag, add `target="_blank"`.